# Acesso a Banco de Dados usando Java

Tags: java, postgresql

Como fazer para acessar um banco de dados (eu estou usando o PostgreSQL) através do Java? Já vi um jeito que usa objetos do tipo `Connection` e `PreparedStatement`.
[[link]](http://www.devmedia.com.br/integrando-programa-java-com-um-banco-de-dados/25880)

Alguém pode me explicar sobre esses objetos ou dar uma forma melhor de acessar o banco? Até a parte da ligação entre o código e o banco eu já fiz, mas o resto fica difícil aprender, já que não há muito disso na internet.

No meu caso, como estou criando uma aplicação pequena, gostaria do modo mais simples de se editar tabelas no banco de dados, com algo parecido com o que vi no tutorial.

Comment: Existem diferentes maneiras de realizar a conexão com o banco de dados PostgreSQL, a mais conhecida é a JDBC e a ODBC, utilizando servidores como o Wildfly a conexão também pode ser realizada utilizando JNDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa é uma dúvida comum para quem começa com Java.

## JDBC

Primeiro, entenda que existe uma API chamada [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) que engloba tudo o que é necessário para se conectar a um banco de dados no Java.

Com raras exceções, esse padrão é utilizado para se conectar a todos os bancos de dados a partir de um aplicativo Java. Mesmo tecnologias de mais alto nível com JPA e outros ORMs usam JDBC como base.

Entretanto, por ser muito genérico, o JDBC é também difícil de entender e confuso a princípio.

## Drivers

JDBC é apenas uma API, ou seja, um conjunto de interfaces e padrões.

Para se conectar efetivamente, cada Banco de Dados deve implementar um Driver que gerencia o seu protocolo de comunicação específico.

Alguns drivers mais simples usam a tecnologia ODBC, que é um padrão genérico de comunicação. Esses drivers são mais lentos e apresentam menos recursos de otimização.

Outros drivers chegam a implementar o protocolo nativo do Banco de Dados, permitindo acesso completo e máxima otimização.

Veja mais sobre os tipos de drivers [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC).

## `Connection`

Uma vez que você tem um banco de dados e o Driver JDBC, você então pode usar a API do JDBC para [estabelecer uma conexão com o Banco de Dados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

Uma das formas de se conectar diretamente ao banco de dados é utilizando o método `DriverManager.getConnection()` e informando a `URL` e os dados de acesso.

Lembro que **URL** significa Identificador Universal de Recursos, não confundir com o endereço de uma página na web.

Se tudo der certo, o método acima irá retornar um objeto [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), que representa a conexão do programa com o Banco.

### *Connection Pool*

Aplicativos desktop geralmente abrem uma conexão com o Banco e usam a mesma até o programa acabar.

Aplicações web atendem dezenas, centenas, milhares de usuários e não podem se dar ao luxo de abrir e fechar conexões a todo momento. Nesse caso usa-se um pool de conexões, que consiste em manter um determinado número de conexões abertas e reusá-las para atender aos vários usuários.

### JNDI

Quando você distribui seu aplicativo Java para uso de terceiros em Servidores de Aplicação como Tomcat, Websphere ou Weblogic, não é uma boa ideia deixar usuário e senha do banco de dados em arquivos de configuração ou *hard coded* no código.

Quem deve configurar a conexão com o banco é o administrador do ambiente e não o programador.

Para resolver esse problema, utiliza-se da API JNDI para disponibilizar conexões com o banco de dados. JNDI basicamente é um índice onde se colocam objetos compartilhados que podem ser acessados por um nome ou `String`.

Então, o que servidores de aplicação fazem é pegar as conexões configuradas pelos administradores e disponibilizar para as aplicações que são instalados no diretório JNDI.

Quando sua aplicação é instalada no servidor, ela pode acessar a conexão por um nome.

### DataSources

Outra API comumente usada para evitar passar usuário e senha para todo o programa.

Um `DataSource` é um objeto *factory* que é capaz de criar uma conexão com seu método `getConnection`.

A ideia é que um lugar apenas do programa crie um `DataSource` e nas outras classes apenas se use o objeto para obter as conexões.

Uma grande vantagem do uso de `DataSource`s é que você pode usar o padrão de projetos *decorator* para interceptar a criação de conexões. Isso permite fazer desde análise de desempenho, cache de conexões e até verificar se o código não está fechando conexões adequadamente.

## `Statement`

Uma vez que você tem a conexão, vai querer executar comandos, certo? Pois é exatamente o que são *statements*.

[`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) é uma interface que representa um comando que você vai executar no banco de dados, tal como um `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `SELECT` e outros.

[`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) permite criar comandos cujos parâmetros são enviados separadamente. Isso melhora o desempenho caso a consulta seja executada várias vezes e também torna a passagem de parâmetros segura, evitando ataques de SQL Injection causados por concatenação de parâmetros em consultas.

[`CallableStatament`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) permite executar *stored procedures*.

## Arquitetura

Tudo isso explica como lidar com conexões. Cada aplicação precisa entender como otimizar isso para o melhor desempenho.

Não existe um jeito certo para todos os casos. Você terá que analisar como seu programa acessa os dados e com que frequência.